# What does <for> and <in> do together in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Here's my Python code

```
thisdict =  {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

thisdict["year"] = 2018
for x in thisdict:
   print(x)
```

It outputs:

```
brand
model
year
```

I can't understand the logic!!

Comment: `for x in thisdict` produces a sequence of dictionary keys.

Comment: Have you searched for "python for in"? There are a million tutorials out there that cover this.

Comment: @PeterWood Which kind of sequence?

Comment: Yash, does it matter what kind of sequence?

Comment: You can see that the output is a list of keys for the dictionary, no?

Comment: @Yash: Why should it change anything if you use `y` as a variable name. It's just a name. The main point is: When you loop over a dictionary you'll get back the keys. Whether you store the current key in a variable named `x`, `y` or `foobarbaz` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

`for a in b` **iterates** through `b` by calling `iter(b)` first to get an iterator of `b`, and repeatedly calling `next()` on the iterator and assigning the values to `a` before running the loop body.

An iterator of a python dictionary generates all its **keys**, so you're getting all keys of `thisdict` with `x` in your loop and printing them.

Answer (score 0):

The [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) loops through the keys in the [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). To loop through and get the values of each key you could do ([Try it online](https://repl.it/repls/WornFrighteningLamp)):

```
for x in thisdict:
   print(thisdict[x])
```

and it would output:

```
Ford
Mustang
2018
```

Comment: @roganjosh Nope 2018 is correct, because the value is changed